# Pandas Groupby apply function to count values greater than zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Pandas Groupby apply function to count values greater than zero

I am using groupby and agg in the following manner:

```
df.groupby('group')['a'].agg({'mean' : np.mean, 'std' : np.std})
```

and I would like to also count the values above zero in the same column ['a']

the following line does the count as I want,

```
sum(x > 0 for x in df['a'])
```

but I can't get it work when applying to groupby.

Following an example for applying a pandas calculation to a groupby I tried:

```
df.groupby('group')['a'].apply(sum(x > 0 for x in df['a']))
```

but I get an error message:
AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute '**module**'

Can anybody please suggest how this might be done?

Comment: `.agg({'pos':lambda ts: (ts > 0).sum()})`

Comment: @behzad.nouri you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

```
 .agg({'pos':lambda ts: (ts > 0).sum()}) # –  behzad.nouri Mar 31 at 0:00
```

This is my contribution to the backlog of unanswered questions :)
Credits to behzad.nouri

**Update 2020**
In the latest pandas version, you need to do the following:

```
 .agg(pos=lambda ts: (ts > 0).sum())
```

otherwise it will result in the following error:

```
SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```