# Count items greater than a value in pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the Yelp dataset and I want to count all reviews which have greater than 3 stars. I get the count of reviews by doing this:

```
reviews.groupby('business_id')['stars'].count()
```

Now I want to get the count of reviews which had more than 3 stars, so I tried this by taking inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751498/pandas-groupby-apply-function-to-count-values-greater-than-zero):

```
reviews.groupby('business_id')['stars'].agg({'greater':lambda val: (val > 3).count()})
```

But this just gives me the count of all stars like before. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it? What am I doing incorrectly here. Does the lambda expression not go through each value of the stars column?

EDIT:
Okay I feel stupid. I should have used the sum function instead of count to get the value of elements greater than 3, like this:

```
reviews.groupby('business_id')['stars'].agg({'greater':lambda val: (val > 3).sum()})
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try to do :

```
reviews[reviews['stars'] > 3].groupby('business_id')['stars'].count()
```

Comment: Cool! That works. Thanks so much. I am a bit new to pandas, so do you mind telling me a bit about how your grouping method works as compared to the way I have grouped data. Is either of them more efficient?

Comment: It's better I think to use "mask" syntax when filtering your dataset than to go through all your data.

Comment: http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~stevel/504/Pandas%20DataFrame%20Notes.pdf   
This is a really good cheat sheet you can use when dealing with pandas

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help!

Comment: however, this will fail to tell you which business_id's have a count of zero

Answer (score 5):

As I also wanted to rename the column and to run multiple functions on the same column, I came up with the following solution:

```
# Counting both over and under
reviews.groupby('business_id')\
       .agg(over=pandas.NamedAgg(column='stars', aggfunc=lambda x: (x > 3).sum()), 
            under=pandas.NamedAgg(column='stars', aggfunc=lambda x: (x < 3).sum()))\
       .reset_index()
```

The **pandas.NamedAgg** allows you to create multiple new columns now that the functionality was removed in newer versions of pandas.

Comment: Short format now available: `reviews.groupby('business_id').agg(over=('stars', lambda x: (x > 3).sum()), under=('stars', lambda x: (x < 3).sum())).reset_index()`

Answer (score 3):

### Correct Query

#### Python

```py
# Pass a df and apply the lambda function to column stars
reviews.groupby('business_id').apply(lambda df: sum(df.stars > 3))
```

#### Code Explanation

```py
lambda df: sum(df.stars > 3)
```

This lambda function requires a pandas DataFrame instance then filter `if df.stars > 3`. If then, the lambda function gets a `True` else `False`. Finally, `sum` the `True` records.
Since I applied `groupby` before performing this lambda function, it will `sum` `if df.stars > 3` for each group.

---

#### Equivalent SQL Statement

```sql
SELECT
    business_id,
    SUM(IF(starts > 3, 1, 0)) AS starts_>3
FROM reviews
GROUP BY business_id;
```

OR

```sql
SELECT
    business_id,
    COUNT(IF(starts > 3, 1, NULL)) AS starts_>3
FROM reviews
GROUP BY business_id;
```

---

### Wrong Query

#### Python

```py
reviews[reviews.stars > 3].groupby('business_id').size()
```

OR

```py
reviews[reviews.stars > 3].groupby('business_id')['stars'].count()
```

---

#### Equivalent SQL Statement

```sql
SELECT
    business_id,
    SUM(IF(starts > 3, 1, 0)) AS starts_>3
WHERE starts > 3
FROM reviews
GROUP BY business_id;
```

OR

```sql
SELECT
    business_id,
    COUNT(IF(starts > 3, 1, NULL)) AS starts_>3
FROM reviews
WHERE starts > 3
GROUP BY business_id;
```

---

#### Why Wrong?

As you can see, the wrong Python query used `reviews[reviews.stars > 3]` to filter the stars that are greater than 3 before `groupby('business_id)`, which is equal to applying `WHERE stars > 3` before `GROUP BY business_id` in SQL.

Therefore, assume you have a `business_id` with only records `stars <= 3`. The wrong query will IGNORE this `business_id`. And you WON'T count them.

---

### Any improvement?

Yes. You can improve the python query to rename the query result. Pandas is not as convenient as PySpark, but we can still name the column name.

```py
# Pass a df and apply the lambda function to column stars
lambda_func = lambda df: pd.Series({'stars_>3': df.stars > 3})
reviews.groupby('business_id').apply(lambda_func)
```

---

### Evaluation

#### Generate Sample Dataset

You can use the following code for evaluation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

# define business_ids
business_ids = range(1, 4)

# define stars
stars = range(1, 6)

# Generate a sample table reviews
reviews = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['review_id', 'business_id', 'stars'])
for business_id in business_ids:
    for i in range(random.randrange(1, 5)): # Assume each business_id has 1~4 reviews
        review = [len(reviews)+1, business_id, random.choice(stars)]
        reviews.loc[len(reviews)] = review
reviews
```

My sample dataset:

|  | review_id | business_id | stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 8 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 9 | 3 | 3 |
| 9 | 10 | 3 | 1 |
| 10 | 11 | 3 | 3 |

---

#### Correct Python Query

```py
"""
business_id, stars_>3
1, 3
2, 1
3, 0
"""
# Pass a df and apply the lambda function to column stars
lambda_func = lambda df: pd.Series({'stars_>3': sum(df.stars > 3)})
reviews.groupby('business_id').apply(lambda_func)
```

|  | stars_>3 |
| --- | --- |
| business_id |  |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

---

#### Wrong Python Query

```py
reviews[reviews.stars > 3].groupby('business_id')['stars'].count()
```

Output:

```
business_id
1    3
2    1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation how your code works and why your answer may be better from the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but my solution is:

```
reviews.groupby('business_id').stars.apply(lambda x: len(x[x>3]) )
```

I came across this thread in search of finding "what is the fraction of values above X in a given GroupBy". 
Here is the solution if anyone is interested:

```
reviews.groupby('business_id').stars.apply(lambda x: len(x[x>3])/len(x) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I quite like using [method chaining with Pandas](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining) as I find it easier to read. I haven't tried it but I think this should also work

```py
reviews.query("stars > 3").groupby("business_id").size()
```

Answer (score 0):

For perfromance first create mask and then aggregate `sum`:

```
(reviews['stars'] > 3).groupby(reviews['business_id']).sum().reset_index()
```