# Pandas Groupby: Aggregate and Conditional

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I am grouping by item-date pairs in a PD dataframe and would like to add some custom conditional functions using lambda to a larger aggregation function.

Using the tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710811/count-items-greater-than-a-value-in-pandas-groupby), I can do the following, which works properly and counts positive and negative values in the given column.

```
item_day_count=item_day_group['PriceDiff_pct'].agg({'Pos':lambda val: (val > 0).sum(),'Neg':lambda val: (val <= 0).sum()}).reset_index()
```

And I can also do a different aggregate that contains both pre-built aggregations and a custom percentile function that returns proper stats:

```
item_day_count_v2=item_day_group['PriceDiff_pct'].agg(['count','min',percentile(25),'mean','median',percentile(75),'max']).reset_index()
```

But I cannot figure out how to combine these into one larger function - I get the error : `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'name'` when I try the below:

```
item_day_count_v3=item_day_group['PriceDiff_pct'].agg(['count',{'Pos_Return':lambda val: (val > 0).sum(),'Neg_Return':lambda val: (val <= 0).sum()},'min',percentile(25),'mean','median',percentile(75),'max']).reset_index()
```

Does anyone know how to combine these functions? Seems like it I am close considering both work separately. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't advise combining a defined func in a dict and native aggregators like that. You can pass them as a list of tuples with function name and function as follows:

```
item_day_count_v3 = item_day_group['PriceDiff_pct'].agg([
    ('Count', 'count'), 
    ('Pos_Return', lambda val: (val > 0).sum()), 
    ('Neg_Return', lambda val: (val < 0).sum()), 
    ('Mean', 'mean'), 
    ('Median', 'median'), 
    ('25%Percntile', percentile(25)), 
    ('75%Percntile', percentile(75)), 
    ('Max', 'max')
]).reset_index()
```

Function name will be the column name.

Answer (score 0):

From pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) on the aggregate() method:

> Accepted Combinations are:
>
> - string function name
> - function
> - list of functions
> - dict of column names -> functions (or list of functions)

I would say it doesn't support all combinations, though.

So, you can try this:

Get everything in a dict first, then agg using that dict.

```
# The functions to agg on every column.
agg_dict = dict((c, ['count','min',percentile(25),'mean','median',percentile(75),'max']) for c in item_day.columns.values)

# Append to the dict the column-specific functions.
agg_dict['Pos_Return'] = lambda val: (val > 0).sum()
agg_dict['Neg_Return'] = lambda val: (val <= 0).sum()

# Agg using the dict.
item_day_group['PriceDiff_pct'].agg(agg_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, you cannot mix named functions with a dict in the `agg()` method.

Here's a practical way to do want you want. Let's make up some data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['x', 'y']*3,
                   'B':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})

df
Out[38]: 
   A   B
0  x  10
1  y  20
2  x  30
3  y  40
4  x  50
5  y  60
```

Define a function to count values greater than or equal to 30.

```
def ge30(x):
    return (x>=30).sum()
```

Now use your custom func in the `groupby().agg()`.

```
df.groupby('A').agg(['sum', 'mean', ge30])
Out[40]: 
     B          
   sum mean ge30
A               
x   90   30    2
y  120   40    2
```