# Pandas groupby where the column value is greater than the group's x percentile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['Abby', 'Abby', 'Abby', 'Abby', 'Abby', 'Daniel', 'Daniel', 'Daniel', 'Daniel', 'Daniel']
df['Marks'] = [100, 90, 76, 50, 10, 50, 45, 38, 25, 5]
```

I want to:

1. Find the 40th percentile for each group
2. Filter the dataframe such that all the values above the 40th percentile for that group are shown.

So, I have found the 40th percentile for each group using:

```
df.groupby('Name').quantile(0.4)
```

The Aim is to get to:

[image]

My main issue is that the values for each group are not standardized and so I cannot apply an overall percentile value for the entire dataset.

But all the help I saw regarding filtering a dataframe with a certain value does not do it separately for each group. I have seen the following questions:

[Pandas, groupby where column value is greater than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632784/pandas-groupby-where-column-value-is-greater-than-x)

[Pandas Groupby apply function to count values greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751498/pandas-groupby-apply-function-to-count-values-greater-than-zero)

My question essentially builds on a variation of the following question:
[Calculate Arbitrary Percentile on Pandas GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894939/calculate-arbitrary-percentile-on-pandas-groupby)

Is there a way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using `transform`

```
df[df.Marks>df.groupby('Name').Marks.transform('quantile',0.4)]
Out[712]: 
     Name  Marks
0    Abby    100
1    Abby     90
2    Abby     76
5  Daniel     50
6  Daniel     45
7  Daniel     38
```

Comment: is it possible to use this approach for the expanding quantile instead of the full-sample quantile?

Comment: I came up with same solution, only 4 mins late:)

Comment: @Yuca what you mean the expending quantile ? I think we can using lambda here

Comment: i'm sure you know about rolling vs expanding in pandas. The expanding quantile would be the quantile available at each rows. I was just curious because I do that with numba and assign

Comment: @Yuca `df.groupby('Name').Marks.expanding().quantile(0.5)
`

Answer (score 1):

Using your code for percentiles, and `loc`, `ge` for `>=` (or `gt`, for `>`) and index matching:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
df.loc[df.Marks.ge(df.groupby('Name').quantile(0.4).Marks)]

    Name    Marks
0   Abby    100
1   Abby    90
2   Abby    76
5   Daniel  50
6   Daniel  45
7   Daniel  38
```